# I cant import the Zxing library

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing

I am working with Unity to make app interfaces and I need to make a QR code reader in my app and the tutorial that I've watched used a library called `ZXing`, but when I try to import it with `using ZXing;` it gives an error saying that this library doesn't exist, how can I import it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havr you installed ZXing via the NuGet paket manager? There is a C# implementation called [ZXing.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/0.16.6?_src=template). The easiest way to install is directly via Visual Studio.